# Error while Converting Date Using Convert.todatetime function.in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a date time field to be saved and updated..my system datetime format is `dd/MM/yyyy`
after saving it in sql server ..while retrieving date i m displaying it in `MM/dd/yy` format.

I have some other date textboxes also in which I am by default displaying the current date using function

`System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();`

or say

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

while updating data it gives me error

> "string was not recognized as valid datetime"

on the line where i m using `Convert.Todatetime(Textbox.Text)` Function in update method

Comment: maybe the text from Textbox is not a valid `DateTime` check it. Then try using `TryParseExact` from `DateTime`

Comment: What string?  Show us...

Comment: I agree with @wudzik. It's most likely an invalid string. Instead of leaving them as plain Textboxes, you could use jQuer and jQuery UI to turn them into Date Pickers.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the replacement character for the current culture's date separator, so if you want to enforce it use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ParseExcat**

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Textbox.Text,
  "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```